# Confuse in using which version of HttpClient in Windows.Web.Http and System.Net.Http;

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-store-apps, httpclient, windows-8.1

I'm new to Web API and Windows Store App 8.1. I'm developing a Windows Store app that communicates to Web API. When I try to write the following code:

```
// server:53452/api/demo?ReportingMonth=10&ReportingYear=2013" 

using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("address")))
            {
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var prodt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Statuses>>(result);
                return prodt;
            }
        }
```

I see that HttpClient is in both  Windows.Web.Http and System.Net.Http. Which namespace should I use?

If I pick the `System.Net.Http` namespace, when I try to call my Web API, which is Windows Authenticate enabled, the cursor will not return back to the client, remaining in unknown state. Not sure about why I'm not receiving the response.

```
address = "abc.com:53452/api/demo?ReportingMonth=10&ReportingYear=2013"
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(address)))
```

If i use `HttpClient` from the `Windows.Web.Http`, windows store app asks me to enter credentials, and even though I entered my credentials correctly, system keeps prompting to enter the credentials. Can anyone explain why that happens?

Comment: [Here's the HttpClient app sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664). As a side note, there is a third version, [Microsoft.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) which is portable.

Comment: The link below states that Windows store apps should use Windows.Web.Http from 8.1 forward. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781239.aspx

Comment: How to perform Windows Authentication to call WEB API from Windows Store, I used previously for System.NET.HtpClient    //HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            //{
            //    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            //};  how to do same thing in windows.web.httpclient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform HTTP authentication, instead of `HttpClientHandler` use `HttpBaseProtocolFilter`:

```
var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.ServerCredential = new 
    Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(uri.ToString(), "foo", "bar");
var client = new HttpClient(filter);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Demystifying HttpClient APIs in the Universal Windows Platform](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/23/demystifying-httpclient-apis-in-the-universal-windows-platform/)

> ### Which one should I use?
>
> Since both of these APIs are available in UWP, the biggest question
>   for HTTP developers is which one to use in their app. The answer is
>   that it depends on a couple of factors:
>
> 1. **Do you need to integrate with native UI for collecting user credentials, control HTTP cache read and write behavior; or pass in a
>      specific SSL client certificate for authentication?**
>
> If yes – then use Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient. At the time of this
>   writing, the Windows.Web.Http API provides greater control over HTTP
>   settings in UWP than the System.Net.Http API. In future versions, the
>   System.Net.Http API may also be enhanced to support these features on
>   UWP.
>
> 2. **Do you intend to write cross-platform .NET code (across UWP/ASP.NET 5/iOS and Android)?**
>
> If yes – then use System.Net.Http API. This allows you to write code
>   that you can re-use on other .NET platforms such as ASP.NET 5 and .NET
>   Framework desktop applications. Thanks to Xamarin, this API is also
>   supported on iOS and Android, so you can reuse your code on these
>   platforms as well.

Comment: Where is ***assembly*** for `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` ? The assembly is `System.Net.Http` for cross-platform.